# Conditionally apply mixin to interface, depending on presence of virtual method

Tags: c++, templates, overriding, c++17, mixins

I've got a bunch of similar interfaces. I have a class template that can implement those interfaces and implement most operations that are common to those interfaces. As a result, I use a mixin on top of those interfaces.

Unfortunately, some of those interfaces are missing some of the common methods.

```
struct Intf1
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct Intf2 {}; // Missing f.
```

I want to apply a mixin

```
template <class T>
struct Mixin
    : public T
{
    virtual void f() override {};
};
```

to a base, exactly if the base class declares a virtual method `f` that the mixin overrides. So, basically I am looking for some meta-programming technique

```
template <template <class> class Mixin, class T> using Magic = ...;
```

such that `Magic<Mixin, Intf1>` is `Mixin<Intf1>` and `Magic<Mixin, Intf2>` is `Intf2`.

At the moment, I am using a separate trait to check whether a method is available in the base class, but this solution has some problems:

- I have to reiterate the function signature.
- I do not definitely know whether the method is virtual (though it seems, this can be done).
- Due to type conversion / const-ness, I may try to override a method that does not match my method's signature perfectly.

I was hoping that there might be a better solution. If my `Mixin` was a class that caused a substitution failure, I'd try something like this: [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxLgDZSAB1QLC62nsMTQS8fNTorG3sjJxdOdyUVMNoGAmZiAgDjU05FZUxVPxS0ggi7R2c3RVT0zKCchWqS6zLoiriASkVUA2JkDgByKQBma2RDLABqcSGdAgBPD0wAfQJiZkIFaexxAAYAQV29huIDVQmASXoqTkPxAHZZfYnniYA3PHSDNjfUPHQJqgQdpTIYAEQmO2mjwOd1BUNu%2B2OpwIFyukimD3ucKG0MOBEwRg8wnxIJ0Y2YCgUEwAKltDkizgBZPAAD2shxeExAEw8BgcrDwyBpt0xTxe70%2B31ev3%2BgOBqFezmIf0wGNksPh%2ByxmoO%2B3xhOJqumZOElImADVSBN9UTmCTjeTKVsJo6qcy2bQra6JtIKZg6YjVsiJnptL46Gw9h4iXhnCLoZyDD5RNaFkawT6/TrtTiEXsbYbSQW7emTRTNkNsC7TW7WdYvTXM0oA0cg2dQ/gkpHowK4zMGugQCBpX8Vsb3eyZr7m5WtlaJ56m/7Z1rRXtE8ngKnFiDwQvjdPl9tc6vsbi9QTbfaZsXr2WnZXq%2BWJguG8/Dy2k9Ytx3w7Ru0SczUru25aMwRiqr%2BXasFGMZ9joI7oPOdaLh%2BlZDvMizZoGdqCks5bOAQEADkOeAKEsCjgcsrzGlBfgAawQHjihVqXAQ1xzi%2BKHGmxHGzpW7Q6g0uHIPhlKEcRBCDiAZEUVRSw0TMdERjBPZMTMr6ouxkicbxOkCdhezKf%2BqmAbSGksVpVD6VWAAaUL9J0rAgP0ACs/SkKY/Q7B5qAuTochyBMCjdL0RqSEMnAeQQLk%2Be0nQANYgNwACcAB0dyuK5OycEMOyudwAAceWSIVvDOf03AeV5PmkH5/QeQoIA7KQMXeY5pBwLAMCICgqCEng7BkBQEBoANQ0oMIogrCctAJaQVCDfixBNRADixR5DjWGkcwbaQY0QfQADytCMXtWBGCIwDsC5UWkPgxD5GoipNe1pCYCy%2BQGPit0edY%2BIVXdAoOGsxBzHoWC/a1ypGL9nQ0PQTBsBwPD8IIU1iIFMhCHgDhNZAnSoB4SSvQAtAO0yghIMhyJItUJE9fiaNotTZO92ilFEMTBN4f6szzoR%2BJz5SxLkiSFI0/P1HkBR0EU6TC60ovCTU%2BhZIIKtNJEItcJ0IU9H0utCC57meXt9UsoVrik643BPimEBBnNwIQLghAkFMEU5CG/UeINzie5FwIBTTMjRRt8WkAgmDMFgLhAsblUebD2Vm299WNc1rUR51PUQEg3QELyBDkJQY1%2BxNOSYJ2JCCAjjAsDdqMAO5rB4cOJ6bNW%2BS5wycBMzeEAgEyW9btv21ujuzQl7Th%2B1kfR7HFQJ0lQx3GlrmJ1VpApy13d1S5mctW1cWJSA2VpRFqVWyl3CuXEKV3HEidDNV5uH9n89OS5khv%2BnH8n0cp0RUK0mbcCAA).

Comment: if the signature does not match then it isnt overriding

Comment: what is `Intf2` ?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Just for clarification: `Intf2` stands for the interface that is missing a method (`f`) that the Mixin would usually implement. The example is already quite minimal, as I left out all the stacking logic for multiple methods and mixins and reduced it down to the the smallest part that I could not solve by myself.

Comment: please include the code in the question

Comment: I think I'm missing something, because your test case can be solved with `std::conditional_t<std::is_abstract_v<T>, Mixin<T>, T>`, but this does not depend on the contents of `Mixin<T>`. What do you want to happen if `T` has a pure virtual function that `Mixin<T>` does *not* override?

Comment: @Quentin: The result does not depend on whether the base class declares other purely virtual methods. If `Mixin` overrides a method `f` in the base class, it is applied. If the base class does not define a virtual method `f` that is overridable by `Mixin`, it is not applied. Tried to clarify in the question.

Answer (score 0):

it's impossible to detect if a function is a virtual function.

but if all pure virtual functions of `T` is overridden by `Mixin`, it works:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct Intf1{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct Intf2 {};

struct Intf3{
    virtual void f2() = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct Mixin : public T{
    virtual void f() {}; // don't mark 'override', it will break SFINAE.
};

template<template<typename>class MixIn, typename T, typename = void>
struct Applier{
    typedef T type;
};
template<template<typename>class MixIn, typename T>
struct Applier<MixIn, T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_abstract<T>::value && std::is_abstract<MixIn<T>>::value>::type>{
    typedef T type;
};
template<template<typename>class MixIn, typename T>
struct Applier<MixIn, T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_abstract<T>::value && !std::is_abstract<MixIn<T>>::value>::type>{
    typedef MixIn<T> type;
};

template<template<typename>class MixIn, typename T>
using applier_t = typename Applier<MixIn, T>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same<applier_t<Mixin, Intf1>, Mixin<Intf1>>::value, "overridden");
static_assert(std::is_same<applier_t<Mixin, Intf2>, Intf2>::value, "not abstract");
static_assert(std::is_same<applier_t<Mixin, Intf3>, Intf3>::value, "not overridden");
```